# Perform operation on columns in pandas data frame and store in new column

Tags: pandas

```
df['TotalCost_BRL'] = df['COM/CHEESE_BRL_weekly'] * df['Barrel_Vol' ]
df['TotalCost_BLK'] = df['COM/CHEESE_BLK_weekly'] * df['Butter_Vol']
df['TotalCost_BUTTER'] = df['COM/BUTTER_weekly'] * df['Butter_Vol']
df['TotalCost_NFDM'] = df['COM/MILK_weekly'] * df['NFDM_Vol' ]
df['TotalCost_Whey'] = df['COM/WHEY_weekly'] * df['Whey_Vol']
```

i want to perform this operation on a for loop for the data frame with index as dates and columns as mentioned in the statements above. Basically I am trying to multiply certain columns on the right and save them in new columns mentioned on the left. Can someone please help me? I am clueless

Comment: What you posted should work without a loop, you need to post raw data, code to create your df, why the above doesn't work and what the desired df looks like

Comment: thanks i just wanted to know a better implementation of doing this